# How to get state value back to clicked button inside mapdispatchtoprops?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new in react and redux. I have a button on a component on click of that I am calling api and set the response as state. But I want that state back to clicked function where on base of that state I want some conditional work.

I dont think how to implement this.

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Could you post the sample code so we don't have to write it from scratch?

Comment: Sorry I am working on live project which is very big.

Comment: So you just need a prototype. I recommend the original docs which are really well written and comprehensive.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Connects a React component to a Redux store.

It does not modify the component class passed to it.
Instead, it returns a new, connected component class, for you to use.

You need to use `mapDispatchToProps` so that your data is back to you at the component once fetched/retrieved making the component re-rendered, and that's what you need and that's the killing feature of `Redux` uni-directional flow archticeture.

Comment: Basim I want to achieve the scenario that if I clicked on a function which is props of a component under dispatch connect which perform an api call and that data will set on a state at that time inside click handler I want to check that data and perform some conditional opeeration.  Is it possible?

Comment: So you need to use `Redux-saga`. It handles what I think you need perfectly. Read more: http://yelouafi.github.io/redux-saga/docs/api/